# Certificate and key abuse

Tags: android, apk, jar-signing, certificate-revocation

I made a mistake several years ago by uploading OpenSSL certificate key (.pem and .pk8) into a blog post. The key was used to sign Android apk using SignApk.jar tool. Someone took it and used the key to sign malware apps and the bad story was i put my email address when created that certificate. This raised issues because people accused me as the creator of those apps.

The question is, how can i recover this situation? some people suggest key revocation, but i don't quite understand it. As far as read from arround the net, the revocation needs  to be uploaded to a CA, what CA?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to raise this question at [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/). I think it is more than a simple "revoke my APK signing certificate". In the Android security model, the certificate is not used to identify you. Google's cookie cutter service does not provide customary RA functions. The certificate and private key is used for continuity so you can update your app. Also see [Code signing in Android's security model](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2013/05/code-signing-in-androids-security-model.html).

Comment: By the way, Thomas J. Hruska and Shining Light Productions caught similar blow back in the Win32 port of OpenSSL. Some malware was using their port and complaints went to Shining Light. Also see their [Win32 OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) page.

Comment: @jww thanks for your response and information, i'll move this question to Information Security Stack Exchange and also check the link you posted.